# Trying to recreate a Datastage job as a Python Script

Tags: python, xml, migration, datastage

I am currently trying to convert a Datastage job into a Python script. My goal is to have the Python script completely replace the Datastage job so it can be retired. I have the XML files of the job but I am having a tough time trying to understand the structure in order to emulate the process in Python. Any tips on this would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried writing the XML information to the python script but I have struggled with this process.

Comment: tip: read the documentation of the datastage to understand how it works, so you can implement the functionality in python

Comment: If you do not know DataStage it will be a huge challenge or nearly impossible to reconstruct / reverse engineer the job. Better is to start with the business requirements from scratch in my eyes or learn and understand DataStage first.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.